# Solving modulo equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What is the simplest way to find all possible solutions for $x^e~ \equiv~ 0 ~~(mod~ n)$? What should be the range of the value of $x$?

Comment: The function $f(x)=x^e$ has a range equal to $\mathbb{R}$. 
So a necessary step is to find all $x$ such that $f(x)$ is equal to an integer.
For a given $n$ there will be infinite many solutions. Whether they show some periodicity that allows to express them in a closed type is debatable. May I ask where you found this?

Comment: There is no source to this question. I was just trying to solve problems on modular equations, so I cooked up this question and wondered whether I can find solutions efficiently in some closed form. I know possible solutions are infinite.